# Search bar to ListView return blank values and getFilter error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, excel, listview

I need to add a search bar in my app, but all the tutorials I tried is not working. Because I want this bar to return the values ​​of my ListView imported from Excel (I applied in a way that the Activity shows the names of people). My ListView is imported from Excel, not created in-app code.

That is, when I search for "A" all the names of the ListView with "A" appears when I search "Arn", appear the names containing "Arn" (E.g. Arnold Clinton).

This is the code of `TabelaActivity.java`:

```
package com.akzonobel.malote.tabela;

import com.akzonobel.malote.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TabelaActivity extends Activity {
    CSVAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabela);

        ListView mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mList);
        mAdapter = new CSVAdapter(this, -1);

        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    }
```

This is the code of `CSVAdapter.java`:

```
package com.akzonobel.malote.tabela;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CSVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<State>{
    Context ctx;

    public CSVAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

        this.ctx = context;

        loadArrayFromFile();    
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){

        TextView mView = (TextView)convertView;
        if(null == mView){ 
            mView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
            mView.setTextSize(19);
            mView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        mView.setText(getItem(pos).getName());

        return mView;
    }

    private void loadArrayFromFile(){
        try {
            InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open("states.csv"); 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                State cur = new State();
                cur.setName(line);

                this.add(cur);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

This is the code of `State.java`:

```
package com.akzonobel.malote.tabela;

    public class State {

    private String name;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

I tried to apply this search bar:

```
EditText inputSearch;
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                TabelaActivity.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
    }
```

The search bar works, can you enter. But when I type the value... it just does not return anything, goes blank. Any help? How to make it work? Or is there another easy way to make a search bar? Can the ActionBar.. the important thing is it works.

Then I tried to apply the getFilter in CSVAdapter, but then when I try to use the bar with this getFilter, it crashes and closes alone.

This is the code I applied `getFilter`:

```
private List<State> allModelItemsArray;
private List<State> filteredModelItemsArray;
private Filter filter;
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null){
          filter  = new ModelFilter();
        }
        return filter;
      }
private class ModelFilter extends Filter
    {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
            {
                ArrayList<State> filteredItems = new ArrayList<State>();

                for(int i = 0, l = allModelItemsArray.size(); i < l; i++)
                {
                    State m = allModelItemsArray.get(i);
                    if(m.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                        filteredItems.add(m);
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            }
            else
            {
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    result.values = allModelItemsArray;
                    result.count = allModelItemsArray.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            filteredModelItemsArray = (ArrayList<State>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for(int i = 0, l = filteredModelItemsArray.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(filteredModelItemsArray.get(i));
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
```

And when this is active getFilter, besides closing, it gives the following error in LogCat:

```
07-13 08:32:52.925: W/Filter(30254): An exception occured during performFiltering()!
07-13 08:32:52.925: W/Filter(30254): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 08:32:52.925: W/Filter(30254):    at com.akzonobel.malote.tabela.CSVAdapter$ModelFilter.performFiltering(CSVAdapter.java:129)
07-13 08:32:52.925: W/Filter(30254):    at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
07-13 08:32:52.925: W/Filter(30254):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 08:32:52.925: W/Filter(30254):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-13 08:32:52.925: W/Filter(30254):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
07-13 08:33:14.856: D/AndroidRuntime(30254): Shutting down VM
07-13 08:33:14.856: W/dalvikvm(30254): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41101930)
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254):    at com.akzonobel.malote.tabela.CSVAdapter$ModelFilter.publishResults(CSVAdapter.java:156)
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254):    at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-13 08:33:14.876: E/AndroidRuntime(30254):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You pass -1 to CSVAdapter() constructor.  Is that correct?  Looks like it should be a textViewResourceId.

Comment: @PeterQuiring I do not know, I got this code in [GitHub](https://github.com/FoamyGuy/CSVListExample)

Comment: According to the source it's not used.  A dummy value.  Sorry.

Comment: When does allModelItemsArray get set?  I think it's null which is causing the NPE in performFiltering()

Comment: @PeterQuiring How so? What can I do to solve then? Sorry, I am high school student and am new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a constructor to the State class:

```
public State(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

Don't use the global allModelItemsArray and filteredItemsArray, get rid of them.

Then change your performFiltering function like this:

```
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
            {
                ArrayList<State> filteredItems = new ArrayList<State>();

                for(int i = 0, l = getCount(); i < l; i++)
                {
                    State m = getItem(i);
                    if(m.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                        filteredItems.add(m);
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayList<State> allItems = new ArrayList<State>();
                for(int i = 0, l = getCount(); i < l; i++)
                {
                    State m = getItem(i);
                    allItems.add(m);
                }
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    result.values = allItems;
                    result.count = allItems.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

This will work much better and is proper way to fix this.

Comment: This code worked, stopped returning null values​​. However, it only returns those names defined. How to put back my Excel spreadsheet into CSV? (The `loadArrayFromFile`)

Comment: Ok, edited to show how to fix the loadArrayFromFile function.

Comment: Sorry for the mess.  Bottom line, don't use allModelItemsArray, this data should be in the CSVAdapter itself.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either.  I think I was right the first time.  This code is a mess...

Comment: When is data suppose to get added to the CSVAdapter?  From the loadArrayFromFile or the publishResults() function?  Both of them can't do that or your data will duplicate ????

Comment: Oh man! Thank you, this worked! Now just have a simple flaw: when I search the name, it returns what I googled, but when I delete, it does not return all the items on the list anymore.

Comment: I ask sincerely apologize for my mistakes and confusion and work I'm giving you. You are helping me a lot!

Comment: When I delete my research, the list does not show all the names again. How to solve this?

Comment: I don't know.  I saw the NPE and figured that would solve it.  I don't understand how the ArrayAdapter is suppose to work, sorry.